# acces constructor function private propriety php

Tags: php, oop

I have this code:

```
class Person { 
     private $_firstName; 
     private $_lastName; 
     private $_age; 

     public function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $age) 
     { 
    echo 'Welcome '.$this->_firstName. ' '. $this->_lastName. 'that have '.''.$this->_age.'<br />';

     }

}
$obiect = new Person("dan", "Marian", 30);
```

why don't displays Welcome dan marian that have 30?

Comment: Which language is this? use tags!

Comment: Because `$this->_firstName` and others were never set in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you do not set values to the members:

```
public function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $age) 
{
    $this->_firstName = $firstName;
    $this->_lastName = $lastName;
    $this->_age = $age;

    echo …
}
```

Comment: how can i acces constructor when create an object StenSoft?

Comment: Constructor is automatically called when you create the object with `new`

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are trying to access the value before initializing, you should try this

```
public function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $age) 
 { 
     $this->_firstName=$firstName;
     $this->_lastName=$lastName;
     $this->_age=$age;

echo 'Welcome '.$this->_firstName. ' '. $this->_lastName. 'that have '.''.$this->_age.'<br />';

 }
```